# How to compare current boolean value to the previous value?

Tags: java, android, boolean, compare

I need to compare the current boolean value to the previous value used to be exist . something like the following example :

```
 private boolean f = false;

 f=true;

 if(f.preivousValue == f.currentValue){}
```

how can I get to it?

Comment: you mean lets say you have used f = false; and then you exit from activity/class/whatever and then you come back and want to compare current values before exiting to th previous one. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your own data structure. For example:

```
 public class StateAwareBoolean {

        private boolean oldState = false;
        private boolean currentState;

        public StateAwareBoolean(boolean value) {
            currentState = value;
        }

        public void set(boolean newState) {
            oldState = currentState;
            currentState = newState;
        }

        public boolean oldState() {
            return oldState;
        }

        public boolean currentState() {
            return currentState;
        }
    }
```

Usage will be something like this:

```
private StateAwareBoolean f = new StateAwareBoolean(false);

f.set(true);

if(f.oldState() == f.currentState()){}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another variable that will store the original value before asigning the new one.

If you want to reuse it for some reason you can create a class called, for example, "BooleanWithPrevious", and inside this class you will also have two booleans, the actual value and the previous. Using a setter you can update both values and then with the getters take the previous and the current value.

TL;DR

You need an auxiliary variable to achieve what you want. Primitives only have an actual value and don't remember anything.